# No se muestran los graficos de plotly.express

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Buen dia.

Sucede que intento reproducir el siguiente ejemplo que saqué de la web de Plotly  en Spyder y no se despliega la gráfica.

```
import plotly.express as px
data_canada = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")
fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop')
fig.show()
```

Esto mismo me pasa con todos mis trabajos, incluso aquellos que ya había graficado antes.

¿Alguien sabrá como solucionar esto?

Comment: Seguramente tengas que ejecutar antes una celda con el _magic command_ `%matplotlib inline` (y en ese caso el `fig.show()` sería innecesario)

Comment: Acabo de probar %matplotlib inline y no funciono :(

Comment: En ese caso quizás deberías poner el código de todas las celdas anteriores, pero no como imagen sino como texto, para que otro pueda tratar de reproducir el problema. En la pregunta usa una línea de ``` delante del código y otra detrás, para que salga correctamente formateado.

Comment: Gracias, si, también he intentado reproducir las gráficas ejemplo que vienen en la página de Plotly en Spyder y no funcionan.

Comment: Pues si antes te funcionaba y ahora no, algún problema de configuración o vete tú a saber. El caso es que es imposible de reproducir en otras máquinas, por lo que el único consejo posible es... ya sabes... reinstala. Aunque de momento y antes de plantearte una solución tan drástica a lo mejor te interesa probar Google Colab. Es un entorno web para ejecutar notebooks, gratis, con muchos paquetes científicos preinstalados. Acabo de probar el código de tu pregunta tal cual y sale un gráfico de barras. Puede servirte para salir del apuro y generar la gráfica que necesitas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, en Google Colab funciona perfectamente. Ya intente reinstalar con y sin anaconda y no funcionó, no entiendo porque pero al menos ahora ya tengo una alternativa para continuar con mi trabajo, mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Mi equipo tendrá alguna configuración que no me permite usar Plotly en Spyder ni Jupyter, pero en Google Colab pude continuar con mi trabajo.